# Extracting specific types from a tree

Tags: haskell, tree

I have built a tree from which I want to collect all the Leaf types:

```
Branch [] (Branch [0] (Leaf [0,1]) (Branch [0] (Leaf [0,2]) (Branch
[0] (Leaf [0,3]) (Leaf [0])))) (Branch [] (Branch [1] (Leaf [1,2])
(Branch [1] (Leaf [1,3]) (Leaf [1]))) (Branch [] (Branch [2] (Leaf
[2,3]) (Leaf [2])) (Branch [] (Leaf [3]) (Leaf []))))
```

What I get as a type in GHCI (`:t`) of the above variable is :

```
Tree [Int]
```

The data structure is the following:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

I am trying to isolate *ONLY* the leaves such that I would obtain :

```
[ [0,1], [0,2] .. [3], [] ]
```

I've been trying to run a `filter` on the results, however that doesn't work. I've tried to using the function `Data.Foldable.toList`, however it pulls all the branches in as well and results in a large list of lists with multiple duplicates and no possibility to tell whether it's a branch or a leaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although other approaches exist, probable the easiest one is to use recursion. Here the base cases are `Empty` and `Leaf`. In case of an `Empty`, we return an empty list, in case of a `Leaf`, we can return a list with *one* element: the one wrapped in the leaf, so:

```
leave_elements :: Tree a -> [a]
leave_elements Empty = []
leave_elements (Leaf x) = [x]
leave_elements (Branch ...) = ...
```

We still need to fill in the `Branch` case, here we see three elements in the constructor: `a`, which we can ignore, and the two subtrees. We can recursively call the `leave_elements` recursively on the subtrees, and append the lists of the data of the leaves of the subtrees. For example:

```
leave_elements :: Tree a -> [a]
leave_elements Empty = []
leave_elements (Leaf x) = [x]
leave_elements (Branch _ l r) = leave_elements l ++ leave_elements r
```

For your given sample tree, this produces:

```
Prelude> leave_elements (Branch [] (Branch [0] (Leaf [0,1]) (Branch [0] (Leaf [0,2]) (Branch [0] (Leaf [0,3]) (Leaf [0])))) (Branch [] (Branch [1] (Leaf [1,2]) (Branch [1] (Leaf [1,3]) (Leaf [1]))) (Branch [] (Branch [2] (Leaf [2,3]) (Leaf [2])) (Branch [] (Leaf [3]) (Leaf [])))))
[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]
```

We can also boost performance by using for instance a tail we pass recursively:

```
leave_elements :: Tree a -> [a]
leave_elements = go []
    where go tl Empty = tl
          go tl (Leaf x) = (x:tl)
          go tl (Branch _ l r) = go (go tl r) l
```

Or we can work with `Data.DList`:

```
import Data.DList

leave_elements :: Tree a -> [a]
leave_elements = toList . go
    where go Empty = empty
          go (Leaf x) = singleton x
          go (Branch _ l r) = append (go l) (go r)
```

Comment: Extra credit: use `Data.DList` instead of list append for an asymptotically faster traversal.

Comment: @luqui: I don't think we need to pass `DLists` per se, we can emulate that with recursively passing a future tail.

Comment: yeah same diff.   I like DList because it is clearer to me what's going on -- we're just using a different representation of a list.  That parameter could be anything; `go (go tl r) l` is just a way of saying "append" but it's rather obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

A more advanced technique, which saves you the effort of writing and maintaining recursive functions by hand, is to use a generic programming library such as [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens)'s [`Plated` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html).

Here's how `Plated` works: you describe how to identify a value's *children* - immediate substructures having the same type as the value itself - by writing an instance of the [`Plated` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#t:Plated), and the library's various higher-order functions take care of recursively finding the children's children and so on. In the case of your `Tree` datatype, only the `Branch` constructor has children (the left and right children), so those are the only places we apply `f`.

```
instance Plated (Tree a) where
    plate f (Branch x l r) = Branch x <$> f l <*> f r
    plate f t = pure t
```

(If you're willing to derive `Data` then you don't even have to write `plate`.)

`Plated`'s [`universe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:universe) function can now recursively search a tree's children, and the children's children, and so on, returning a lazy list which yields every node in the tree. It works roughly like this:

```
universe :: Plated a => a -> [a]
universe t = t : [descendant | child <- toListOf plate t, descendant <- universe child]
```

So to find all the leaves, you just have to filter this list to search for `Leaf` constructors.

```
leaves :: Tree a -> [a]
leaves t = [x | Leaf x <- universe t]
```

Job done!

Answer (score 0):

As @BenjaminHodgson notes in the comments the following solution is valid, but cannot have a consistent implementation across other typeclasses. For example making `Tree` an instance of `Traversable` would result in an implementation of the `traverse` function that necessarily touches all elements of the `Tree`. I am leaving this up for learning purposes, but don't use this solution.

Using the [`Foldable` typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html):

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

instance F.Foldable Tree where
    foldMap f Empty = mempty
    foldMap f (Branch x l r) = foldMap f l `mappend`
                               foldMap f r
    foldMap f (Leaf x) = f x
```

For your `tree`:

```
Prelude> foldr (\x acc -> x: acc) [] tree
[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is not a good example of a `Foldable` instance. While it’s not law-breaking per se (because `Foldable` doesn’t have any laws to speak of), it’s widely agreed upon that a `Foldable t` instance should pick _all_ of the `a`s out of a `t a`, not just some of them. Since `Tree` as written can be made an instance of `Traversable`, this `Foldable` instance wouldn’t agree with such a `Traversable` instance.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thanks for the feedback - I'm new to Haskell. What's the downside of creating a type that only allows access to some of its data? Wouldn't the `Traversable` implementation do the same thing (traverse only the leaves)? In other languages data structures that hide some of their data may be unorthodox sometimes but not necessarily a bad idea.

Comment: That’s a good question. The `Traversable` instance _cannot_ leave any of the `a`s where they are because of the type of `traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`. All of the `a`s in the `t` must be transformed into `b`s.

Comment: Generally speaking, the notion of data hiding is not a bad thing at all. It allows you freedom of choice in the way your datatype is implemented. Haskell programmers use data hiding just as much as the next guy. However hiding values whose type is chosen by the user just doesn’t make sense as an engineering decision: such data must have been supplied by the user in the first place so why hide it?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Good point... Also for the `Tree` to be traversable it must be a functor, and if it only traversed its leaves it would violate the functor identity law. I'm going to make note of your comments and leave the answer up for posterity. Thanks for the intel!